# reference for doing send audio file by offset android

Tags: android, offset

i am making audio live streaming application. what i was doing before, i recoded voice/audio for certain time and i will push the stop button to stop the recording.

then i put action to send the video after clicking the stop button to server through internet. in here i am using socket programming. it works perfectly however i was not live streaming application.

i have heard about doing the code offset to send the audio file to make it live. it will send bytes by bytes of the audio to the server. however, so far i could not find any reliable tutorial/simple source code of how i would like to do it. does anyone knows where i could fine any reference regarding this method?